# How to create files from a list which contain space

Tags: xargs, touch

I would like to create files from the following list.

There is no problem if the list doesn't have a space ... but the problem is it has a space

```
user@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
Apples
Bing Cherry
Crab Apples
Dragon Fruit
user@linux:~$
```

**Before**

```
ser@pc:~$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 44 Jun   9 14:06 file.txt
user@linux:~$
```

**xargs touch**

```
user@linux:~$ cat file.txt | xargs touch 
user@linux:~$
```

Instead of creating `Apples, Bing Cherry, Crab Apples, Dragon Fruit`, the command producing these output.

**After**

```
user@linux:~$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Jun   9 14:11 Apples
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Jun   9 14:11 Bing
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Jun   9 14:11 Cherry
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Jun   9 14:11 Crab
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Jun   9 14:11 Dragon
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 44 Jun   9 14:06 file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Jun   9 14:11 Fruit
user@linux:~$
```

What should I do to handle space in this situation?

Comment: See also the section of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/116858) labelled "What's wrong with xargs?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `xargs`, you can specify newline as the separator with the `-d`/`--delimiter` option:

```
xargs --no-run-if-empty --delimiter='\n' --arg-file=file.txt touch --
```

With short options:

```
xargs -r -d '\n' -a file.txt touch --
```

Comment: touch: unrecognized option '--delimiter=\n'

Comment: ugh thinko. fixed.