# How do I create multiple files names from list.txt in bash?

Tags: bash, files, touch

I want to create multiple files at a time using names from a file `list.txt`, how can I do it?

Sample `list.txt`:

```
EOG090W002U
EOG090W00C1
EOG090W00DC
EOG090W00DE
EOG090W00E5
EOG090W00HR
EOG090W00MH
EOG090W00MS
EOG090W00PB
EOG090W00U4
EOG090W00UK
EOG090W00WM
EOG090W00WR
```

Suppose I have this `list.txt` containing some id-numbers. Now I want to make separate files using these ids as the name (e.g. `EOG090W002U_M0.ctl`, `EOG090W00C1_M0.ctl`, `EOG090W00DC_M0.ctl`). Also, the contents of the files need to be change accordingly. For example the content of `EOG090W002U_M0.ctl`, `EOG090W00C1_M0.ctl` file will be

```
seqfile = EOG090W002U_p.phy
treefile = Constant.txt
outfile = EOG090W002U_M0_mlc
```

or

```
seqfile = EOG090W00C1_p.phy
treefile = Constant.txt
outfile = EOG090W00C1_M0_mlc
```

where `*.phy` and `Constant.txt` will be provided in the same folder.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to explain _where_ you want the newly created files to be placed, if you simply want to create empty files, and whether the filename is to be amended by a suffix etc.

Comment: "multiple files at a time"? Please be more clear.

Comment: Please don't change your question so much that it becomes a new question.   You have now invalidated all answers.  You can ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest:

```
xargs touch <List.txt
```

The magic is that `xargs` takes every line in its stdin and adds it as an argument to the command.

Comment: Although not needed in this case (since the strings don't contain whitespace) a more general solution would be `xargs -d '\n' touch <List.txt`. See for example [How to create files from a list which contain space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523804/how-to-create-files-from-a-list-which-contain-space)

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU parallel in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

constant=constant

populate_file () {
    local const=$1
    local file=$(basename -s '.M0.ctl' "$2")
    printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' \
    "seqfile = ${file}_p.phy" \
    "treefile = ${const}.txt" \
    "outfile = ${file}_M0_mlc" > "$2"
}

export -f populate_file

parallel populate_file "$constant" {}.M0.ctl :::: list.txt
```

This will read lines from `list.txt` and execute the `populate_file` function against each one in parallel.  The `populate_file` function will output the three lines in the desired format into each file.

In the absence of GNU parallel you can use a while read loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

constant=constant

populate_file () {
    local const=$1
    local file=$(basename -s '.M0.ctl' "$2")
    printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' \
    "seqfile = ${file}_p.phy" \
    "treefile = ${const}.txt" \
    "outfile = ${file}_M0_mlc" > "$2"
}

while IFS= read -r file; do
    populate_file "$constant" "${file/ /}.M0.ctl"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry that it shows an error that parallel: command not found. I think I should ask another question.

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj: Install GNU parallel.

Comment: Thanks, @Jesse_b the 2nd one working for me, but there is little problem that it is creating space before the extension in the file name as well as inside the filename. 

seqfile = EOG090W0AK7
_p.phy
treefile = SameTREE.txt
outfile = EOG090W0AK7
_M0_mlc

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj: Ah, it sounds like your file may have spaces at the end of each line, I'll update a bit later to remove them

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj: I've updated the second solution to remove the whitespace

Comment: No difference, same output...

Comment: Well do some investigating into what is wrong with your input then.  We have identified that your input has some weird whitespace issues and I don't have your input so you need to do a little leg work and figure it out.  If there were trailing tabs it wouldn't produce the same output you are describing so I don't know what the problem is.  Maybe you just need to `dos2unix` your file or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:
`for i in $(cat list.txt); do touch $i; done`

Comment: for loop is discouraged to read from file. use `while` instead.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. I am a very beginner in programming , I explaing the entire things.

Comment: @DebajyotiKabiraj: You can read about it more on the [bash pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) wiki

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' < list.txt | 
  while IFS= read -r word; do
   touch "$word";
  done
```

This answer has been provided with the assumption that all "words" in file was in the same (first) line and where separated by blank characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

tr -d '[:blank:]' < list.txt > outputFile.tmp

for i in $(cat outputFile.tmp)
do
  echo "seqfile = ${i}_p.phy" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "treefile = constant.txt" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
  echo "outfile = ${i}_M0_mlc" >> ${i}_M0.ctl
done
exit 0
```

Explanation:

1. `tr -d '[:blank:]' < list.txt > outputFile.tmp` will remove blanks from list and copy it to `outputFile.tmp`
2. `for` loop reads all lines from `outputFile.tmp` and adds the necessary context to the files by creating them on the fly.

Comment: Hello, Thanks 
The desired results is not coming,...

seqfile = EOG090W01HI
_M0.ctl_p.phy
treefile = constant.txt
outfile = EOG090W01HI
_M0.ctl_M0_mlc

The space is still there and in addition _M0.ctl is included in in the text which is not needed and spaces are still remained

Comment: I have updated the answer; now please try.

Comment: Hi Thanks,
I tried it gives different kind of outcome..
The file name EOG090W076L?.ctl 
and inside the file name the results are like...
_p.phye = EOG090W076L
treefile = SameTree.txt
_M0_mlc = EOG090W076L

Comment: This script was verified and it worked perfectly at my machine. I am using Cygwin terimnal. Try doing dos2unix on your list.txt and then try the script. Don't copy the script using copy paste. Create new script by typing the lines.